# How to distinguish between "so many" and "such many" semantically?

Tags: adverbs

Would you please show me the difference in meaning between these?

1. > They have introduced **so** many cars that…
2. > They have introduced **such** many cars that…

Comment: A look at a dictionary would show you that "such+many"  does not occur. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/such?q=such

Comment: @rogermue: Not sure I'd generally consider that the most reliable way to determine this: expecting *all possible usage patterns* to be in a dictionary is the error meatie falls into. Usually, they will be included, but proving a negative like this is a rather tougher thing than simply going and finding the correct meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it simply, one is wrong and one is right. You'll *never* see "such many." "**So** many" is the correct usage.

You could use "such" if you were expressing the degree of an adjective. For example:

> They release **such beautiful** cars nowadays.

or in the singular:

> They unveieled **such a beautiful** car today.

In all of these cases, the noun has to follow the adjective. You can't have "The car they unveiled is such beautiful" - that is incorrect.